# Using accents in Vim seamlessly

Tags: vim, special-characters

Very often I need to write text/program in foreign languages that need accents and special characters in vim, but sometimes it is very hard to get that working.
What are the best alternatives to configure vim for that task?

Comment: first step is setting tty. does `echo é` on comand line give é (test can be made on any non 7-bit char)?

Answer (score 10):

The best approach is to first modify Vim configuration files to automatically load your configurations.

It can be done by writing the following lines to either `~/.vimrc` if you want just to your user or `/etc/vim/vimrc` if you wish it applied to every user.

```
syntax on
set autoindent
set smartindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set encoding=utf-8
```

Then, it is necessary to add some language setting to your environment, by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

IMPORTANT:

To force vim to put a real tab, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd> in “insertion mode”.

Another thing to observe is that if you need some characters like "á", "ô", "ü" and "ÿ", for example, and can't get your system to map them, there is a nice trick on Vim that put these characters right at your need:

In insertion mode type
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and then a sequence, like **a'** or **a>** and you will get **á** and **â** respectively.